# check for a pattern from a line in file and count the number of lines which are matching the pattern

Tags: awk

I am having a directory called **checks** and in that a file called **true.txt** as below:

```
Column1     column2     column3     column4     column5
Data        25          gen(*)      87          65  
Stem        34          gen(*)      23          76
Invert      36          gen($)      89          67
Delete      32          gen($)      43          23
print       34          gen(*)      34          34
ctrl        23          gen($)      33          43
```

I need to count the number of lines containing **gen(*)** and number of lines contaiing **gen($)**, irrespective of column1, and in some situations in **column3 gen($)** may not there then I need to print it as zero, I shared the output syntax for reference and desired output like below:

```
output syntax:
Directoryname : count of gen($)     count of gen(*)

output:
checks : 3  3
```

I tried this code but not getting the exact output:

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in checks
awk 'BEGIN
FNR==NR
/gen \(\*\)/{
  tot=FNR
  next
}
END{
  print "checks : ",tot-1
}
' true.txt
```

Comment: The code you posted would produce a syntax error from shell and also a syntax error from awk, not `not getting the exact output`. Post actual code for us to be able to best help you.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. Written and tested link
https://ideone.com/xBrCzc

```
awk '
$3=="gen(*)"{ countGenstar++ }
$3=="gen($)"{ countGendollar++ }
END{
  print "Count: ",countGenstar+0,countGendollar+0
}' Input_file
```

Comment: The script is working perfectly for the given samples, what if the directory name changes? can we use like this : at the starting use ....for d in directoryname and while printing the output can we use : print "$d:", countGenstar+0,countGendollar+0

Comment: @ADAPANIKHIL, you could use awk script in a find command and of you have GNU awk use ENDFILE for printing at each file, I am in cab now written this on mobile you could it self and let me know how it goes :)

Comment: I'm not getting it, Can you please edit in the code as second answer?

Comment: I tried the code suggested by you, I am getting the output like this: **Count: 3 3** , but I need the output syntax like this: **Directoryname: 3 3** , sometimes the directory names may be changing.

Comment: @ADAPANIKHIL, sorry I am outside and not on system will write it once I am on system

Comment: Can you please explain about these two lines in the code ..  
 **sub("/[^/]+$","",dir)** and **sub(".*/","",dir)**

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need this to be done using only `awk`?
`Grep` can solve this problem very easily:

```
fgrep -c "gen(*)" true.txt
fgrep -c "gen($)" true.txt
```

In case you don't have `fgrep`, it's the same as `grep -F`.

Comment: But then you better do: `fgrep -c "gen(*)" true.txt`

Comment: `fgrep` is deprecated in favor of `grep -F`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '
    { cnt[$3]++ }
    END {
        dir = FILENAME
        sub("/[^/]+$","",dir)
        sub(".*/","",dir)
        print dir, ":", cnt["gen($)"]+0, cnt["gen(*)"]+0
    }
' $HOME/checks/true.txt
checks : 3 3
```

Comment: I need to create this script in this directory $HOME/script.sh or here $HOME/checks/script.sh ?

Comment: Create it wherever you like. Try whatever you think is right and then ask a specific question about your attempt if you have one after running it.

Comment: Can you please explain about these two lines in the code .. **sub("/[^/]+$","",dir)** and **sub(".*/","",dir)**

Comment: Why not just put `print dir` statements around them so you can see what they do? In any case - `FILENAME` is `/your/home/checks/true.txt` so `dir` starts out as that then the first sub removes the actual name of the file `/true.txt` and the second one removes `/your/home`, thus leaving `dir` as the directory name you want printed, `checks`.